# urlrewritingnet whats max number of friendly URLs can set up?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

Hey I am using urlrewritingnet to create some rewrite rules in  asp.net. The whole concept is fine, but I seem to be getting into trouble with the volume of links I am trying to put in the config file.

I.e in my externalRewrite.config file I have listed as follows

add name="orgId-O977" virtualUrl="^~/orgprofile/overview/AOIBHNEAS-LIMITED.aspx" destinationUrl="~/orgprofile/overv.aspx?Id=977" ignoreCase="true" />

But I have around 40,000 links in this config file, with just a few thousands is fine but when I have all my links the just stuck on loading and seems to never end ?

Comment: but is it possible to do this using the custom provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind the above, went with ISS7 Rewrite just proved a better solution